# Can I use jquery Mobile with HTML 4.01?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

Can I use [jQuery mobile library](http://jquerymobile.com/) with `HTML 4.01 transitional` or do I have to use `HTML5` to use it?

Comment: What version of jQuery you can use is completely irrelevant to what version of HTML you use. HTML 4 vs HTML 5 really doesn't matter to jQuery.

Comment: Ok thank you, i've just think that the mobile version work only with css3 and html5 bcause all the documentation is in it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use **both** with jQuery Mobile. Just choose the one appropriate on your case.

For that you might need to know some of the differences among mobile technology regarding web and versions of different html.

I suggest reading these articles.

1. [HTML 4/5 Mobile Applications](http://www.developria.com/2010/08/html45-mobile-applications.html)
2. [HTML 5 in mobile devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_in_mobile_devices)
3. [HTML 4.0 Guidelines for Mobile Access](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-html40-mobile/)

Comment: Sorry bu I don't understand your point.. can I use html 4.01 with jqueryMobile or I can just use jqueryMobile with HTML5.

Sorry i'm not english, maybe your answer is clear but i think i don't read it correctly

Comment: both html 4 and 5 is Ok, with mobiles, just choose what is best for you.